# javascript: из массива значений сформировать массив с накопленными значениями

Tags: javascript, массивы

есть массив содержащий данные в виде `[year, count]`

надо получить массив содержащий уже накопленные за все предыдущие годы значения, но в том же виде - `[year, count]`

пример данных:

```
input: [[2010, 10], [2015, 2], [2022, 8]]
output: [[2010, 10], [2015, 12], [2022, 20]]
```

сделал в лоб:

```
    // подготовить данные
    let data_accum: [number, number][] = [];
    let count:number = 0;
    data.forEach((value: [number, number]) => {
        count += value[1];
        data_accum.push([value[0], count]);
    });
```

Такой вопрос - а как это сделать покрасивше, что называется "в одну строчку"?

**P.S.**

другой вариант:

```
let data_accum = [];
data.reduce((total, value) => {
    data_accum.push([value[0], total + value[1]]);
    return total + value[1];
}, 0)
```

избавляется от инициализации счетчика

Comment: "покрасивше" и "в одну строчку" --- это понятия, которые часто противоположны.  В целом, какой смысл переводить в одну строку такой простой код? Чтобы потом другой разработчик сидел гадал, что там происходит? Зато "модно молодёжно"

Comment: ну например - избавиться от инициализации счетчика (это можно сделать через обращение к последнему элементу массива) или попробовать через map собрать

Comment: Ну а зачем? Я понимаю, если код был бы хотя бы в 20+ строк, но зачем код, который ясен, превращать в кашецу?  ЗЫ: это тайпскрипт?

Comment: да, тайпскрипт, но это не очень критично

Comment: добавь пример с данными: что на входе и что ожидается на выходе

Answer (score 0):

```
data_accum = data.map((value, i, arr) => [value[0], value[1] + arr.slice(0, i).reduce((total, elem) => total + elem[1], 0)])
```

Нашел решение, но оно все таки очень неоптимальное, хотя для коротких массивов имеет право на жизнь :(

другой подход, лишенный предыдущих недостатков и немного короче:

```
data_accum = data.reduce((total, value) => [...total, [value[0], value[1] + (total.length ? total[total.length - 1][1] : 0)]], [])
```

или так:

```
data_accum = data.reduce((total, value) => [...total, [value[0], value[1] + total[total.length - 1][1]]], [[0, 0]]).slice(1)
```